# PHP Paypal recurring payment

Tags: php, paypal-subscriptions

Hi
Can someone please explain me if "PayPal recurring payment" and "Paypal subscription" are the same thing?

Like I am working on a monthly membership payment integration with php and paypal. What I need to do is make this go on forever until the member decides to opt out. I am using this class found at www.micahcarrick.com/php-paypal-ipn-integration-class.html for the integration.

In the class you can mention like for how long you would like to make it as recurring payment but there are no options to make it go forever like a monthly subscription thing. Please help!

Many thanks in advance and I really appreciate your help :-))

Answer (score 1):

These are not the same thing. A standard PayPal account can create subscriptions but not recurring payments. If you plan to use IPN as your only integration, you need to create subscriptions, not recurring payments. You do not create them programmatically, you just generate a subscription link and the buyer creates the subscription on the PayPal website.

Recurring payments are part of one of the APIs accessible to PayPal Website Payments Pro accounts.

Comment: Please note there are some limitations when it comes to recurring payments, it is not possible to make one if the customer is from Germany. We had to learn that the hard way :) See https://www.x.com/message/175024#175024, last comment.